# Need CSS Styling same as shown in the Image

Tags: css

I have  a tool tip , I want to have the look of the tooltip as shown in this image 
as shown

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=fa381ec

I have tried this way , but its not working 
could anybody please let me know how to achive this ?

```
.flotr-mouse-value {
    font-size: 10px;
    border: 45px solid #12a1da;

}
```

Comment: Did you generate the tooptip with a javascript library?  If so, you need to tell us how you did it.  There is no way to answer this question as-written.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference

Comment: I am uisng http://www.humblesoftware.com/finance/index for this , as you see the tooltip in black color ,i want it in my customized color

Comment: Inside Flotr.js File , i have found this line                                                          elStyle = 'opacity:0.7;background-color:yellow;color:#fff;position:relative;padding:2px 8px;-moz-border-radius:4px;border-radius:4px;white-space:nowrap;';

Comment: I have solved the problem , than you very much .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
<div id="tooltip">
    <div class="contents">
        contents of the tooltip
    </div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

and the style:

```
#tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
}
#tooltip div.contents {
    background: #ccc;    
    height: 150px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666;
}

#tooltip div.arrow {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    bottom: -10px;
    background: url(arrow_down.gif) no-repeat;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666;
}
```